# vuejs listening for event on component

Tags: javascript, events, vuejs2

I am unable to catch the **flash** event on my custom component that i am emitting from the console . Here is my component:

```
/* file flash.vue */

<template>
  <span :class="type" class="alert flash-alert" v-show="show">
    {{ body }}
  </span>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['type','message'],
    data() {
        return {
            body: this.message,
            show: false,
        };
    },

    created() {
        if(this.body)
        {
            this.showComp();
            this.hide();
        }
    },

    methods: {
        showComp: function(){
            this.show = true;
        },

        hide: function()
        {
            var vm = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                vm.show = false;
            },2000);
        },
    },

    events: {
        flash: function(newMessage) {
            this.body = newMessage;
            this.showComp();
        },
    }
}
```

on the chrome console i am firing the event with:

```
/* from console */
window.vueEventBus = new Vue();
window.vueEventBus.$emit('flash','my message');
```

the event is firing as i can see that on the vue devtools tab. But upon catching the event the component should become visible, which is not.

However, if i piggyback the listener on the global event bus inside the components **created()** method, it works.

```
created() {
  window.vueMessageBus.$on('flash',newMessage => {
      this.body = newMessage;
      this.showComp(); 
    });
 }
```

What should i do if i want the event listener to be registered inside the **events** property of the component itself?

-Thanks, Yeasir

Comment: There's no such thing as an `events` property in Vue 2.

Comment: But there was one in vue1 right? I started learning vue with vue2 and sometimes running into examples from vue1 probably, as I have seen the events object on both parent and.child components!!

Answer (score 11):

look this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3xyx386q65)

eventbus created in **index.js**

```
Vue.prototype.$vueEventBus = new Vue()
```

listener on (see *components/eventBus/eventBus.vue*)

```
created() {
  this.$vueEventBus.$on('message-in', this.newMessage)
},
beforeDestroy() {
  this.$vueEventBus.$off('message-in')
}
```

emit event (see *components/eventBus/childEventBus.vue*)

```
methods: {
  newMessage(something) {
    this.$vueEventBus.$emit('message-in', something)
  }
}
```

app page https://3xyx386q65.codesandbox.io/eventBus

Comment: in most of the examples i have seen the event listener is attached to the component inside the **created** hook. Are there any specific reasons? What if i want to do it inside the **mounted** hook?

Comment: yes, replace created() with mounted(), and it will be work. Do not forget to remove  listener. Also see vue instance [Lifecycle Diagram](https://vuejs.org/images/lifecycle.png)

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems there is a loop in the code that you shared here. For the **message-in** event to be emitted the __newMessgae__ function has to be called, which in-turn depends on the event **message-in**!! Right? Anyways, my question was actually whether there is an **event** property to a vue instance in vuejs2. Thanks for the example though :)

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder, see documetation  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events