# VueJS: Call method from component using eventbus

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using VueJS and want to trigger a method inside a .Vue component. The eventbus is working properly. I have created this according this article: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Within the eventbus function I want to call the method from the component. How can I do this? I tried this.doSearch(), but this doesn't work. Any advises?

```
//Event listener
EventBus.$on('i-got-searched', search => {
    if (!(search === undefined || search === null)) {
        console.log(`Debug: ${search}`)
    }
});

//Component
export default {
    methods: {
        doSearch(input) {
            console.log(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754830/vuejs-listening-for-event-on-component/47759612#47759612

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue's ref directive should work for you:

```
<search-comp ref="search"></search-comp>
```

And then in your eventbus use:

```
var search = parent.$refs.search;
search.doSearch(val);
```

Here is a working demo:
https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/vpJdQJ

And here is the documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: Calling a component's method from another component is a Bad Practice. The second component should call the method itself when responding to the event, or a different event could be sent to trigger it.

Comment: @RoyJ I agree.  In that codepen link you can also see the two components emitting to each other so they can call their own methods.  I can add that code to the answer too if you think it is more applicable.  Above is a quick solution.

Comment: I think it's an important point to make. I think (though I'm not sure) that the original question is asking for that sort of encapsulation-breakage, which makes me think it should be discouraged.